# Please explain this basic proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

In my freshman math course book there's a proof of associativity
of addition on the natural numbers using mathematical induction. The author proves the base
case and assumes the hypothesis, $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$, holds. The
inductive step for $c:=c+1$ goes like this:
$$a+(b+(c+1)) = a+((b+c)+1) = (a+(b+c))+1 = ((a+b)+c)+1 =
(a+b)+(c+1)$$
, which proves the hypothesis.

Here's the question: why is it wrong to directly state
$a+(b+(c+1)) = (a+b)+(c+1)$ in the inductive step? It was
assumed that $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$ is true, here we take the
$(c+1)$ from $a+(b+(c+1))$ to be the $c$ from  $a+(b+c)$ and
just apply $a+(b+c) = (a+b)+c$.
What's the fault in my reasoning?

Comment: The fault in your reasoning is that : if you take $(c+1)$ in palce of $c$ in the induction hypotheses : $P(c)$, you are assuming that $P(c)$ holds for any $c$, i.e. that $\forall n P(n)$; and you cannot assume it, because this is what you are trying to prove ...

Comment: Simple counter-example : *(i) basis* : $0=0$; *(ii) ind step* : assume : $c=0$; then put $c+1$ in place of $c$ and we have : $c+1=0$. Thus, by *Induction* : $\forall n (n=0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get the assumption of the induction right which is that associativity of addition holds for all natural numbers smaller or equal to c. With only this assumption your task is to show that it holds for c+1. That means you can not take c+1 to be your old c.

Answer (score 0):

Every step in the version in the book is an instance of the axiom (or whatever) $$x+(y+1)=(x+y)+1.$$Your "direct" $$a+(b+(c+1))=(a+b)+(c+1)$$is simply not an instance of that axiom.

Comment: But in mathematical induction after you prove the base case P(a), you can assume P(k) to prove P(k+1), no?

Comment: Yes. You allowed to _assume_ P(k), which is what the author does. And then you have to _prove_ P(k+1). Your version is assuming P(k+1).